# Runtime permission not working on Version 8.0.0 & Version 8.1.0 (React Native - Android)

Tags: android, react-native, runtime-permissions, android-8.1-oreo

**Case Not Working For**

1. CALL_PHONE
2. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
3. CAMERA

**Core Functionality**
Application have QR Code Scanner at its core functionality

**Library Used**

```
react-native-qrcode-scanner
```

**Scenario**
Open App -> Click {Scan QR Code} Button -> App Asks RunTime Camera Permission -> Give Access

**Result**

```
1. Camera not Opening

2. App not able to access Location

3. App Not able to Call
```

**App Level Settings**

```
I am able to see in settings that all Run Time Permission provided is activated in Settings -> Apps -> Permission.
```

**Permission is only not working on Version 8.0.0 & Version 8.1.0. Rest all other Versions including Android Version 9, permission is working like a charm.**

Not able to identify why this is happening.

I seek any suggestions on this.

**UPDATE**

I think at Version 8.1.0, if permission is provided then app is reading it as false and Vice Versa

Comment: Please check this package                         https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the permissions into your `AndroidManifest.xml`, add `tools:node="replace"` for your permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
```

probably you are using a dependency or library that remove the permission.

Comment: Will it be a good choice to have app level permission instead of Lib level permission ... As Ideally over Native part I would have  taken at app level only. I'm new to RN... Any help is appreciated